# Recover Files From Non Bootable Install

Tags: boot, sd-card, restore

I'm working on a project for work involving Python code and some hardware components. I recently attempted to install some drivers to get a small touch screen to work and now my Pi won't boot. I've gone through different methods of troubleshooting for about 3 hours now and I've given up on trying to fix it. I just need to get my files off of the current microSD so I can flash it and start over. I have the contents of the SD copied to my desktop PC. How can I view individual files and remove what I need to?

**tl;dr**: Tried and failed to recover bootable OS. I just want to get my files and start over.

Comment: Duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42962/how-to-make-a-raspberry-pi-sd-partition-accessible-from-windows-and-raspbian

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to mount the SD Card in a reader on any Linux machine, including the Pi. Trying to do on a Windows or Mac is a lot of trouble.

You can mount an image  on any Linux machine.

You can use a Linux bootable CD.

I suggest you get a new SD, install Raspbian and copy the files.

Comment: Thank you. I've been digging around in the files from another raspberry Pi. The files that I needed were all on the desktop and I can't seem to find how to navigate to it.

Comment: @Alexzoin The files hould be in `/home/pi/Desktop` which will probably be mounted in `/media/NAME` or similar, depending how you mount it.